# a metric property: $d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$

$d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$

My professor used the second proposition while introducing metric spaces but some books are using the first proposition instead. Which one is true? Is there a case while $d(x,y)>0$, $x=y$?

Comment: The first one is true. If $d(x,y)=0$ is possible without $x=y$, then we have no metric. In definitions , "iff" is often replaced by "if" , an apparently quite common sloppiness.

Comment: I think your question is incorrect. Both your professor and the books say that, if $x=y$, then $d(x,y)=0$. Where they differ is that the professor allows for $d(x,y)=0$ even if $x\ne y$, while the books don't. *The book definition is the right definition.* However, two points: (a) Perhaps the professor meant to say "iff" ("if and only if") or just got confused; (TBC)

Comment: (b) If you allow $d(x,y)=0$ even if $x\ne y$, you can make an equivalence relation $x\sim y\iff d(x,y)=0$. (**Exercise**: prove that $~$ is the equivalence relation.) With that, you can "identify" all points at mutual distance $0$ and treat them as being the same point. What you get as a result is a (quotient) metric space that would satisfy both your professor and your books.

Comment: The definition $x=y\implies d(x,y)=0$ (professors definition) rules out $x=y$ and $d(x,y)>0$, however it allows $x\ne y$ and $d(x,y)=0$. But as said, a metric does not allow this either.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a case while $d(x,y)>0$, $x=y$?

No. And both definitions imply the opposite. In symbolic terms your properties can be stated as:

$$d(x,y)=0\ \iff\ x=y$$
$$d(x,y)=0\ \Leftarrow\ x=y$$

For the last property typically we would write it in a different order: "$x=y\ \Rightarrow\ d(x,y)=0$" which can be shortened to "$d(x,x)=0$".

Note that these two properties are not the same. While $x=y$ does imply $d(x,y)=0$ in both cases, it is not necessarily true the other way around: that $d(x,y)=0$ implies $x=y$. Unless the first definition is assumed.

> Which one is true?

The true definition of [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)) contains

$$d(x,y)=0\ \iff\ x=y$$

axiom. If we replace that axiom with the weaker

$$d(x,x)=0$$

then we obtain something called [pseudometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space) which is a weaker version of metric. Still useful in some scenarios (e.g. functional analysis), but not as widely used as metric.

> My professor used the second proposition while introducing metric spaces

It is likely to be a mistake on his side (well, I don't believe he would intentionally misguide you). After all, as I said, the second property can be written in a shorter way as "$d(x,x)=0$". Why would he use a longer version then? Likely because he had the first axiom on his mind.